# Join 2 JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two objects:

```
o1 = {
    v1: 10,
    v2: 20
}

o2 = {
    v1: 50,
    v2: 60
}
```

I want:

```
newO = {
    o1: {
        v1: 10,
        v2: 20
    },
    o2: {
        v1: 50,
        v2: 60
    }
}
```

I do this and it works, but I am concerned that `phpStorn` is complaining about syntax (`shorthand property names are not supported by the JavaScript version`).

```
newO = {o1, o1};
```

I tried using `jQuery` but it returns just the second object withing the new object.

```
var newO = {};
$.extend(newO, o1, o2);
```

But I get back `newO = o2`

What is the correct way of joining / concatenating the two objects? Did I misunderstand the `$.extend` function? Thanks

Comment: newO = {o1, o2}; this is perfectly fine

Comment: Well it works, but PHPStorm is adamant it shouldn't... Thanks

Comment: Fix php storm issue after going on settings menu and search for `javascript` with this https://ibb.co/ewApEk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two objects and you want to merge them than you need to create new object and them into a new object

```js
o1 = {
    v1: 10,
    v2: 20
}

o2 = {
    v3: 50,
    v4: 60
}

var str2 = {}
str2.v5 = o1;
str2.v6 = o2;

console.log(str2)
```

like this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
o1 = {v1: 10,v2: 20};
o2 = {v1: 50,v2: 60};

var newobj={o1, o2}
console.log(newobj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```